# Including major minor ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

AS you can see I am having list of dates on x-axis I want to do have major minor ticks instead of showing all the dates like given in this example http://bl.ocks.org/vjpgo/4689130.
This is my html

```
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div align="center">
    From :
    <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To :
    <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
  </div>

  <label> List of Tables : </label>
  <br>
  <form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 50px;">
      <select id="dropdown1"></select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -30px; height: auto;">
      <select id="listbox" , multiple></select>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
```

This  is my link to fiddle showing

http://jsfiddle.net/k013yrgc/29/

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/vjpgo/4689130

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ordinal scale, which will use your unique values and use them for your axis. In your fiddle you can see that you have repeated dates and those dates are not even ordered. The issue is that even though some dates look the same they have different hour, minutes and seconds (you can watch this if you add extra format to your axis).

You should use a time or linear scale if you want to achieve your desired output.

Since your dates are not separated by an equal interval it is hard to render in a nice understanding manner. You can find an updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yh1ptsLw/4/)

```
 var xScale = d3.time.scale().nice(d3.time.day).range([0, width]);
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom')
     .ticks(10).tickSubdivide(3).tickSize(-10, -10, 0)
```

which will have the dates ordered and with the axis with the interval jumps.

Comment: I did like this but then i got error of rangeband not defined so I commented that rangeband but now nothing is coming on my x axis no error nothing..please tell //.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())   this one i commented out

Comment: Yeah, since d3.time.scale does not have the rangeBand function defined your code will throw an error. If you comment the width attribute definition it wont render the bars correctly since the svg element won't have a width.

Comment: so what to do then